# Java Concurrency volatile for reading synchronization for writing

Tags: java, concurrency

I need to create a class that has a shared-between-threads Object (lets call is SharedObject). The special thing about SharedObject is that it holds a String that will be returned in multithreaded environment, and sometimes the entire SharedObject will be written to by changing field reference to newly created object.

I do not want to make the read and write *both* synchronised on the same monitor because the write scenario is happening rarely while read scenario is quite common. Therefore I did the following:

```
public class ObjectHolder {
    private volatile SharedObject sharedObject;

    public String getSharedObjectString() {
        if (!isObjectStillValid()) {
            obtainNewSharedObject()
        }
        return sharedObject.getCommonString()
    }

    public synchronized void obtainNewSharedObject() {
        /* This is in case multiple threads wait on this lock,
           after first one obtains new object the others can just
           use it and should not obtain a new one */
        if(!isObjectStillValid()) {
            sharedObject = new SharedObject(/*some parameters from somewhere*/)
        }
    }
}
```

From what I have read from documentation and on stackoverflow, the `synchronized` keyword will assure only one thread can access the synchronised block on the same object instance(therefore write race/multiple unnecessary writes is a non-issue) while `volatile` keyword on the field reference will assure the reference value is written directly to the main program memory (not cached locally).

Are there any other pitfalls I am missing?

I want to be sure that within synchronized block when `sharedObject` is written to, the new value of `sharedObject` is present for any other thread at latest when lock for `obtainNewSharedObject()` is released. Should this not be guaranteed, I could encounter scenarios of unnecessary writes and replacing correct values which are a big problem for this case.

I know to be absolutely safe I could just make `getSharedObjectString()` `synchronized` by itself however as stated previously I do not want to block reading if not needed. 
This way reading is non-blocking, when a write scenario occurs it is blocking. 
I should probably mention method `isObjectStillValid()` is thread independant (entirely SharedObject and System clock based) therefore a valid *Thread-free* check to be used for write scenarios.

Edit: Please note I could not find a similar topic on stackoverflow, but it may exist. Sorry if that is the case.

Edit2: Thank you for all the comments. Edit because apparently I cannot upvote yet (I can, but it does not show). While my solution is functional as long as `isObjectStillValid` is thread-safe, it can suffer from decreased performance due to multiple accesses to volatile field. I will improve it most likely using the *upgraded* double-checked locking solution. I will also in-depth analyse all the other possibilities mentioned here.

Comment: What you have is mostly OK.  However as pointed out `isObjectStillValid()` still must be thread safe for this to work, and there is no such thing as a "thread-free check" in Java so you should show us that code.  Strings are immutable in Java and can be shared freely between threads, so that's fine.  If you have any other shared fields you should show those too so we can comment.

Comment: The fields are primitives (bunch of Strings) + an actual Date. `isObjectStillValid()` reads the date from the object and compares it with current Date. You are correct in clearly stating the method must be thread safe. However I am only using Date as a comparison point to current Date, so as far as I can tell by quickly checking the Date.after() implementation it appears to only read the internal milisecond count without modifying the state. But to safeguard and futureproof I am thinking switching field type to be fully immutable (actual milis count as Long can suffice here) needs to be done.

Comment: As long as you understand that `Date` and other system timers probably have no better than 10 millisecond resolution, that should be fine.  You do need to make the Date itself visible somehow, perhaps with a `volatile` field.  Again if we could see the code it would be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to format this inside a comment properly. But `isObjectStillValid()` is currently basically a one liner that goes as follows:  `return sharedObject.getDate().before(new Date(System.currentTimeMilis())`. `SharedObject`  class has no API to set any of its fields by themselves; they are only set via a constructor. Any change requires a new instance creation.

Comment: You can edit your question instead of trying to post code in a comment.  We really do need to see the full code including the constructor, but what you have so far is probably OK.  Your ctor piggy-backs its visibility when you assign it to a `volatile` as you do above, and as long as you never change any fields then the result is thread safe.  (C.f. *Java Concurrency in Practice* by Brian Goetz for more information on how piggy-backing works.)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html). It uses optimistic locking, meaning that no actual thread locking is involved. Internally it uses [Compare and Swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap). If you look at the implementation it uses volatile in its implementation and I would trust Doug Lea to implement it correctly :)

Apart from this, there many more ways for synchronization between lot of readers and some writers - [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html)

Comment: This is a good option if you only care that the **first** `SharedObject` created is the one used. However, I will warn against this if construction of `SharedObject` is significantly expensive as this will not protect you against concurrent construction.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a classic [double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java) pattern. While your implementation is logically correct - thanks to the use of `volatile` on `sharedObject` - it might not be the most performant.

The recommended pattern for Java 1.5 on is shown on the Wikipedia page linked.

```
// Works with acquire/release semantics for volatile in Java 1.5 and later
// Broken under Java 1.4 and earlier semantics for volatile
class Foo {
    private volatile Helper helper;
    public Helper getHelper() {
        Helper localRef = helper;
        if (localRef == null) {
            synchronized(this) {
                localRef = helper;
                if (localRef == null) {
                    helper = localRef = new Helper();
                }
            }
        }
        return localRef;
    }

    // other functions and members...
}
```

Note the use of a `localRef` for accessing the `helper` field. This limits access to the volatile field in the simple case to a single read instead of potentially twice; once for the check and once for the return. See the Wikipedia page again, just after the recommended pattern sample.

> Note the local variable "localRef", which seems unnecessary. The effect of this is that in cases where helper is already initialized (i.e., most of the time), the volatile field is only accessed once (due to "return localRef;" instead of "return helper;"), which can improve the method's overall performance by as much as 25 percent.[7]

Depending on how `isObjectStillValid()` accesses `sharedObject`, you might benefit from a similar pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the use of a [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) would be appropiate.

The basic idea is that there can be multiple readers simultaniously or one writer exclusively. Here can you find an [Example](http://www.codejava.net/java-core/concurrency/java-readwritelock-and-reentrantreadwritelock-example) how to use it in a List implementation.

Copy paste in case the side goes down:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

/**
 * ReadWriteList.java
 * This class demonstrates how to use ReadWriteLock to add concurrency
 * features to a non-threadsafe collection
 * @author www.codejava.net
 */
public class ReadWriteList<E> {
    private List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private ReadWriteLock rwLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    public ReadWriteList(E... initialElements) {
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(initialElements));
    }

    public void add(E element) {
        Lock writeLock = rwLock.writeLock();
        writeLock.lock();

        try {
            list.add(element);
        } finally {
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public E get(int index) {
        Lock readLock = rwLock.readLock();
        readLock.lock();

        try {
            return list.get(index);
        } finally {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        Lock readLock = rwLock.readLock();
        readLock.lock();

        try {
            return list.size();
        } finally {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
    }

}
```